What is this houseplant with a red fleshy stem and thick waxy leaves?

Hi I need help identifying this plant. Unfortunately it died recently and I loved it a lot. I want to get a replacement so any help identifying would be appreciated, thank you!

It is Peperomia obtusifolia variegata, sometimes commonly known as baby rubber plant, although rubber plant and Peperomia are not related; they are not from the same plant families.

Baby rubber plant also known as Pepper face and American pepper plant

Hi Paul, you can improve your answer by supplying a link or your own photos.
